# Using Material variables from main styles.scss

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material2

I have the following code in my app `styles.scss`:

```scss
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
// Plus imports for other components in your app.

// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
@include mat-core();

// Define the palettes for your theme using the Material Design palettes available in palette.scss
// (imported above). For each palette, you can optionally specify a default, lighter, and darker
// hue.
$candy-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-blue);
$candy-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-light-blue, A200, A100, A400);

// The warn palette is optional (defaults to red).
$candy-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);

// Create the theme object (a Sass map containing all of the palettes).
$candy-app-theme: mat-light-theme($candy-app-primary, $candy-app-accent, $candy-app-warn);

// Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app.
// Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each component
// that you are using.
@include angular-material-theme($candy-app-theme);
```

How I can use the `$candy-app-primary` color in another component sass file?

```scss
.extend-toolbar {
  background-color: $candy-app-primary; // What I need to import in order to use that, if it's even possible?
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `mat-color` SASS mixin from Angular Material.

Here's some example usage:

```scss
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@import 'app-theme.scss';

.extend-toolbar {
    background-color: mat-color($candy-app-primary);
    color: white;
}
```

For more info, check out the [docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components#using-colors-from-a-palette).

Answer (score 1):

Per the Angular Material docs for version 11.x and below:

> Your custom theme file should not be imported into other SCSS files. This will duplicate styles in your CSS output. If you want to consume your theme definition object (e.g., $candy-app-theme) in other SCSS files, then the definition of the theme object should be broken into its own file, separate from the inclusion of the mat-core and angular-material-theme mixins.

So for these Angular Material versions, it is best practice to not import the file which has the following lines:
`@include mat-core`
`@include angular-material-theme($candy-app-theme)` into another file.  I don't see this stated for version 12.x and above, but it still might be best practice.  I also like to define variables for quick access to the default, lighter, darker and contrast colors of each palette.  So the file setup would look something like this:

`colors.scss`

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

$candy-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$candy-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);
$candy-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);

$candy-app-theme: mat-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $candy-app-primary,
    accent: $candy-app-accent,
    warn: $candy-app-warn,  
  )
));

// for quick access to palette colors, you can also do this for lighter, darker and contrast versions
$primary-color-default: mat-color($candy-app-primary);
$accent-color-default: mat-color($candy-app-accent);
$warn-color-default: mat-color($candy-app-warn);
```

then in `styles.scss`

```
@import '~src/app/styles/colors.scss';

// these next 2 imports shouldn't be imported elsewhere, so don't import this file anywhere else
@include mat-core();
@include angular-material-theme($candy-app-theme);

// the rest of your global styles
```

then lastly, your component is not going to take a palette as an individual background color.  So you cannot assign `background-color: $candy-app-primary`.  Instead I am guessing you want to use the default, 500 color from the palette.  Since we already made quick references to this color its a snap
`my.component.scss`:

```
@import '~src/app/styles/colors.scss';

.extend-toolbar {
   background-color: $primary-color-default; 
   color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create one separate file for `$candy-app-primary`.
this created file include in both style.scss and component scss using `@import`
does this help